# Passing an icon and name from TableviewController B to TableviewController A

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, protocols

I am trying to pass an icon and a name from tableview Controller B to view controller A via a delegate.

To put this simple, a user is presented with ViewController A: (Shown here)

**ViewController A and source code**

[image]

**ViewController A source**

```
 //
 //  MasterTableViewController.swift
 //  Sample image
 //
 //

 import UIKit

 class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController, IconselectedDelegate    {

@IBOutlet weak var passedIconName: UILabel!

var tempname: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   self.title = "Master"
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

}

func iconName(iconName: String) -> String {

    self.tempname = iconName

    self.passedIconName.text = "\(iconName)"

    return tempname!
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

So when when the user taps this cell, the user is then presented with another view controller (viewController B) that shows a list of icons. Here is the Screenshot and source code for this sample.

**ViewController B**

[image]

Here is the sample code for Viewcontroller B
**ViewController B code**

```
//
//  IconTableViewController.swift
//  Sample image
//
//  Created by me on 4/18/16.
//

import UIKit

protocol IconselectedDelegate {
func iconName(iconName: String)-> String
}

 class IconTableViewController: UITableViewController {

enum Icon: Int {
    case Study
    case Apple

    var icon: UIImage {
        switch self {
        case.Study: return UIImage(named: "study")!
        case.Apple: return UIImage(named: "apple")!
        }
    }
}


var icons = ["Study", "Apple"]

var delegate: IconselectedDelegate? = nil
var selectedIndex = 0

// holding vars
var image: UIImage?
var name: String?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.title = "Icon selection"


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return icons.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None {


        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            self.name = icons[0]

        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            self.name = icons[1]
        }


        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    selectedIndex = indexPath.row

    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IconTableViewCell



    // Configure the cell...
    cell.iconName.text = icons[indexPath.row]

    if let iconIndex = Icon(rawValue: indexPath.row) {

        cell.iconPreview.image = iconIndex.icon
    }

    return cell
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    if name == nil {
        delegate?.iconName("None")
    } else {
        delegate?.iconName(name!)
        print("Delegate left with \(delegate?.iconName(name!))")
    }
}


 }
```

**PROBLEM**

I want to pass the selected icon back to the master view controller showing both the name and the icon image. (In master view controller, there is a UIImage object but you can't see it right next to the UILable saying 'select')

How can i achieve this? I used this similar code for accomplishing UIColor and it worked but it does not seem to work with images.

Would greatly help

Comment: I think you are not setting delegate property to self in A Viewcontroller. Refer my answer and manage your code likewise

Answer (score 3):

**Set values from your DestinationViewController back to your Primary (First) ViewController**

**1.** Implement a protocol, for example create a file called protocol.swift.

```
    protocol SetIconValueDelegate {
       func didChoose(icon:Icon)
    }
```

**2.** set the delegate on your second ViewController

```
    class yourNextViewControllerClass {

    var delegate:SetIconValueDelegate?
```

**3.** set the delegate when you load your secondViewController (with Icon Details)

```
    if(segue.identifier == "yourIdentifierInStoryboard") {

        var yourNextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as yourNextViewControllerClass)
        yourNextViewController.delegate = self
```

**4.** add Function to FirstViewController

```
    func didChoose(icon:Icon) {
        // set here whatever you want 
    }
```

**5.** call this function from your SecondViewController

```
     delegate?.didChoose(icon) // this will send your "icon" object - run this from didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

**6.** Set the delegate in your FirstViewController

```
    class FirstViewController: UIViewController, setIconValueDelegate {
```

Comment: By convention, your delegate name should start with an uppercase character: SetIconValueDelegate. Also, a name for the function that would be more in line with Swift's naming would be something like *didChoose(icon: Icon)*   See this accepted proposal for why the word "icon" should be pruned from the method name *didChooseIcon(icon: Icon)*: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - i´ve changed some names now.

Comment: When you refer to "Call this function from your secondViewController", are you referring to adding `delegate?.didChoose(icon)` in the function being implemented in the FirstViewController or do you mean calling this delegate from the secondViewController's methods?

Comment: Yes, with: delegate?.didChoose(icon) (or other function name in that delegate protocol) you can call any function through your delegate from your secondViewController on the FirstViewController.

Comment: I have followed all the steps and i get this error `Cannot convert value of type '(Icon).Type' (aka 'Icon.Type') to expected argument type 'Icon'`. I even tried the lower case 'icon' as an argument in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method in the SecondViewController, Like this -> `delegate?.didChooseIcon(icon) ` and this: `delegate?.didChooseIcon(Icon) `

Comment: Any leads? I cannot seem to solve this one. I already tried many things. Might it be the Enum itself?

Comment: You need to send an Object of type "Icon" - so use let icon = new Icon() (to create a new "Icon" Object. Edit: Ah i see its an enum. So you have to create an enumeration object. Your Problem is your Enum, not your delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delegate(protocol)` methods to send back data to previous view controller.

IN CURRENT VC:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class
{
    func sendArrayToPreviousVC(myArray:[AnyObject])
}
```

Make a var in your class.

```
 weak var mDelegate:MyProtocol?
```

Now call the protocol method when you pop the view controller, with your "properties" array as parameter. (in your case from did select row pass what you want like icon or name)

```
 mDelegate?.sendArrayToPreviousVC(properties)
```

IN PREVIOUS VC:

In your previous VC, set the mDelegate property to self, when you push the current VC.

```
  currentVC.mDelegate = self
  //PUSH VC
```

Now implement the protocol method in your previous VC.

```
 func sendArrayToPreviousVC(myArray:[AnyObject]) {
    //DO YOUR THING
 }
```

This is the scenario that how can send data back in navigation stack. adjust according to your data and requirement.

You should use didselect row delegate method to pass data.
hope this will help :)

Comment: This did not work, All i got was the same exact error from the above answer